Spring Kafka Consumer Fails with ClassNotFoundException for Custom Event Class
I get an error when the provider sends to the consumer as if it did not find the package.
2024-08-27T08:24:53.392-05:00 ERROR 8988 --- [microservice.consumer] [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.CompletedFetch       : [Consumer clientId=consumer-my-group-id-1, groupId=my-group-id] Deserializers with error: Deserializers{keyDeserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer@2d365715, valueDeserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer@c2a6563}
2024-08-27T08:24:53.392-05:00 ERROR 8988 --- [microservice.consumer] [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Consumer exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: This error handler cannot process 'SerializationException's directly; please consider configuring an 'ErrorHandlingDeserializer' in the value and/or key deserializer
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DefaultErrorHandler.handleOtherException(DefaultErrorHandler.java:192) ~[spring-kafka-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.handleConsumerException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1925) ~[spring-kafka-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1348) ~[spring-kafka-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1804) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordDeserializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition providerconsumer-1 at offset 26. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.CompletedFetch.parseRecord(CompletedFetch.java:331) ~[kafka-clients-3.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.CompletedFetch.fetchRecords(CompletedFetch.java:283) ~[kafka-clients-3.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.FetchCollector.fetchRecords(FetchCollector.java:168) ~[kafka-clients-3.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.FetchCollector.collectFetch(FetchCollector.java:134) ~[kafka-clients-3.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.collectFetch(Fetcher.java:145) ~[kafka-clients-3.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.LegacyKafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(LegacyKafkaConsumer.java:666) ~[kafka-clients-3.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.LegacyKafkaConsumer.poll(LegacyKafkaConsumer.java:617) ~[kafka-clients-3.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.LegacyKafkaConsumer.poll(LegacyKafkaConsumer.java:590) ~[kafka-clients-3.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:874) ~[kafka-clients-3.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollConsumer(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1625) ~[spring-kafka-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1600) ~[spring-kafka-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1405) ~[spring-kafka-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1296) ~[spring-kafka-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    ... 2 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The class 'com.microservice.provider.persistence.dto.OrderPlacedEvent' is not in the trusted packages: [java.util, java.lang, com.microservice.provider.persistence.dto.OrderPlacedEvent]. If you believe this class is safe to deserialize, please provide its name. If the serialization is only done by a trusted source, you can also enable trust all (*).
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.mapping.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.getClassIdType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:124) ~[spring-kafka-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.mapping.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.toJavaType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:98) ~[spring-kafka-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:571) ~[spring-kafka-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:73) ~[kafka-clients-3.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.CompletedFetch.parseRecord(CompletedFetch.java:321) ~[kafka-clients-3.7.1.jar:na]
    ... 14 common frames omitted`

@Configuration
public class KafkaProviderConfig {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrapServers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    public Map<String, Object> producerConfig(){
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        properties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        properties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        return properties;
    }
    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, Object> producerFactory(){
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfig());
    }
    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, Object> producerFactory){
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory);
    }


 @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate;
  @Override
    public Usuario saveUser(Usuario user) {
       // log.info("Ingresando al servicio de usuaro service");
        kafkaTemplate.send("providerconsumer", new OrderPlacedEvent(user.getName(),user.getLastname()));
        return usuarioRepository.save(user);
    }

@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrapServers}")
    private  String bootstrapAddress;
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfig() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringDeserializer.class);
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "com.microservice.provider.persistence.dto.OrderPlacedEvent");
        return props;
       /* JsonDeserializer<Object> jsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>();
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
                props,
                new StringDeserializer(),
               jsonDeserializer);*/
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String,Object> consumerFactory(){
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfig());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Object>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
    }

    @KafkaListener(
            topics = {"providerconsumer"}
            ,containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory",
           // clientIdPrefix = "json",
            groupId = "my-group-id"
         )

    public void lister(OrderPlacedEvent Object) {
        //log.info("Mensaje recibido el mensaje es : " + usuario.getName() +usuario.getLastname());
        log.info("Mensaje recibido el mensaje es : " + Object.getNombre());
    }

enter image description here
enter image description here

Where are you seeing ClassNotFoundException? The error says something else... Your trusted packages should not use a class name

I concur with OneCricketeer. How about this instead props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "com.microservice.provider.persistence.dto"); ?
